# Display list passed to listview and return id of selected item to previous activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I am fairly new to Android development, and I would like to make a simple note-taking app as a learning exercise.

I have an activity with an edittext and a menu. when the menu is clicked I would like to display a second activity (or similar) that lets the user select a note that then is returned to the edittext to be edited.

So far all the tutorials I can find use a hard-coded list or a list in a resources file, mine has to be more dynamic.

All help is greatly appreciated as I want to get coding!

Cheers,

Will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't give you complete code as you are learning you should explore it yourself but I would like to give you some hints.

From your first Activity your should start second activity using [startActivityForResult](http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577) which starts an activity and that started activity will return some results to your first activity.

Another thing you can use is [PutExtra](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) which can be used for passing some data from one activity to another.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a dummy way

Create a class `theApp`

```
public class theApp extends Application {
private String Note;

public String getNote(){
    return Note;
    }
public void setNote(String Note){
    this.Note = Note;
    }
}
```

In the manifest (change the  **android:name="theApp"**)

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="theApp">
```

In the first activity (to return to the second activity):

```
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(FIRSTACTIVITY.this,CALLED_ACTIVITY.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key1", whatever);//if you want to send some string
            bundle.putString("key2", whatever);//you can also send integers and others using putInt and others
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In the second activity (to return to the first activity):

```
            ((theApp)getApplicationContext()).setNote(a_STRING);
            setResult(ANY_INTEGER);
            finish();
```

Finally in the first activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // use ((theApp)getApplicationContext()).getNote();
    // if you want you can use ANY_INTEGER (which was set in the second activity using setResult
    // Access ANY_INTEGER using resultCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think JavaNut13 is more concerned about the views in his list and not activities.

@JavaNut13, take a look at http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/